# how to write loop of generators in Simmer environment

Tags: r, loops, queue, simulation

In my queueing application, I have c classes of customers who have different service rate. c can be 5, 10, 15,..., and potentially a very large number. Thus I will need to apply "add_generator" in simmer environment c times. The idea is in the code.

```
env <- lapply(1:100, function(i) { 
simmer("SuperDuperSim") %>%
add_resource("server",capacity=100,queue_size=0) 
%>%
for(j in 1:c){
  add_generator(names[j], class_j_trajectory, 
  at(0)) 
}%>%
run(until=100)
})
```

For loop inside doesn't work. But it's too tedious to write down every class trajectory. Is there any efficient way to add many generators? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop cannot be piped. Use an auxiliary variable as follows:

```
envs <- lapply(1:100, function(i) { 
  env <- simmer() %>%
    add_resource("server",capacity=100,queue_size=0)

  for(j in 1:c) env %>%
    add_generator(names[j], class_j_trajectory, at(0))

  env %>% run(until=100)
})
```